# Reactjs infinity scroll component always render new data

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, concatenation, next.js

After scroll, my data always renders to **page 2** and **page 1** is gone and `items.concat` is not working

Fetch data code:

```
const FetchUrl = async (p) =>{
    const Url = await fetch(`api-link=${p}`);
    const data = await Url.json();
    setItem(data.DataNonProject.data)
}
```

Code to fetch more data:

```
const fetchMoreData = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setPage(page + 1);
        console.log(page);
        FetchUrl(page);
        setItem(items.concat(Array.from(items)));
    }, 100);
    // FetchUrl(page);
 }
```

Return data:

```
{items ? 
    <InfiniteScroll
      dataLength={items.length}
      next={fetchMoreData}
      hasMore={true}
      loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
    >
     {console.log(items)}   
        { items.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
                div {index} - # {item.title}
                <br/><br/><br/>
            </div>
        ))}
    </InfiniteScroll>
    : '' }
```

I'm using `react-infinite-scroll-component`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const FetchUrl = async (p) =>{
  const Url = await fetch(`https://softkomik.site/api/komik-list?page=${p}`);
  const data = await Url.json();
  setItem(prev => [...prev, ...data.DataNonProject.data])
}
```

```js
const fetchMoreData = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setPage(page + 1); // At this point, page state will not be changed because setPage is async function
        FetchUrl(page + 1);
    }, 100);
 }
```

Comment: i got error `TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.`. any solution?

Comment: `setItem(prev => [...prev, ...data.DataNonProject.data]);`

Comment: what is the type of `item`? also type of `data.DataNonProject.data`?

Comment: item is useState `const [items, setItem] = useState();`

Comment: change to `const [items, setItem] = useState([]);`